# Display Custom Fields in Theme (processwire)

Tags: field, processwire

I created custom field impressum_text in Processwire and now I need display this field in my theme. How can I please display this custom field in my theme (in file _main.php)?

Can you help me, please?

[custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSIIj.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You simply output `$page->impressum_text`

This can be direct via `echo $page->impressum_text` or you can assign it to a variable like:

`$out = $page->impressum_text` in your page's template file eg basic-page.php

and then echo the $out in your _main.php